# how to access child component data in template?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quasar

I'm trying to access the computed property "files" of this component

https://quasar.dev/vue-components/uploader#quploader-api (if you go into the link theres a menu explaining this component, on the option "computedProps" theres info related to this files property I'm trying to access)

this is my current template

```
<template>
  <q-dialog ref="dialogRef">
    <q-card class="q-dialog-plugin" style="width: 700px; max-width: 80vw;">
      <q-form class="q-gutter-md exportForm">
        <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
              <div>
                <div class="fileUploaderContainer">
                  <q-uploader ref="fileUploader" class="fileUploader" url="http://localhost:4444/upload" :style="{display: 1 > 0 ? '' : 'none', 'max-width': '250px'}"/>
                  <div class="fileUploadInitializer" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background: #f00;" @click="startUploader($event)" >

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">col-8</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </q-form>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>
</template>
```

script code:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { QUploader, useDialogPluginComponent } from 'quasar';
import { nextTick, onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const fileUploader = ref()
const files = ref([]);

function startUploader(event: MouseEvent){
  console.log('test');
  fileUploader.value.pickFiles(event)
}

defineEmits([...useDialogPluginComponent.emits]);


</script>
```

this "q-uploader" as I said before has a "files" computed property which is a Array, I wish to hide it based on the lenght of this array on the :style attribute

I've tried $this, this but nothing seems to work!

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess  computed can be taken directly, and then used v-if control to show and hide

Comment: how to I access it? the q-uploader files variable

Comment: You can use ref

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using ref (template code has ref="fileUploader") then I try to use it like fileUploader.files.length and it shows this error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')

Comment: ohh， If you use vue2, it seems to use this.$refs.fileUploader, right? If vue3 is used, you can defineExpose({files}) in the child component and then use fileUploader.files in the parent component. You can try

Comment: this is a third party library, meaning I cannot edit the code of this child component, its prebuilt :/

Comment: OKK, Well, I'll take a look at the api...

Comment: Did you try it with $refs.fileUploader？

Comment: yeah, but I think its because the component hasnt finished loading and since I'm trying to access that component property on the template while it doesnt exists it shows the error :/, maybe this isnt allowed in vue?

Comment: umm，Perhaps， could you show your script

Comment: and you can try it in nexttick